# Add elements from XAML to grid defined in code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, code-behind

I generate Rows and Columns based on user input, but I do this in code behind. But then I want to add elements like Buttons or textblocks using XAML. Any suggestions? Or is there any way to generate rows and columns using XAML?

```
Grid grid = new Grid();
grid.ShowGridLines = true;
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
      ColumnDefinition column = new ColumnDefinition();
      RowDefinition row = new RowDefinition();
      grid.RowDefinitions.Add(row);
      grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(column);
}
this.Content = grid;
```

Then I want to add a button like this:

```
<Button Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="1">

</Button>
```

Comment: I find it hard to understand your requirement.

Comment: The recommended way to build ui dynamically is to build xaml as a string and then xamlreader.parse it into controls.  https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/28797.wpf-dynamic-xaml.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define the `Grid` to add the `Button` to in the XAML as well then. Where would you define the `Button` element otherwise?

Give the `Grid` an `x:Name` in the XAML markup:

```
<Window...>
    <Grid x:Name="root">
        <Button Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="1">

        </Button>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

...and then refer to it by this name in the code-behind when you add the rows and columns to it:

```
root.ShowGridLines = true;
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    ColumnDefinition column = new ColumnDefinition();
    RowDefinition row = new RowDefinition();
    root.RowDefinitions.Add(row);
    root.ColumnDefinitions.Add(column);
}
```

Note that you should not create another `Grid` or set the `Content` of the view in the code-behind where you generate the rows and columns.

Comment: Thanks, it worked!!